# Conflicts caused by the use of kafka and HBase

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hbase

When I use "spark streaming" to read "kafka" (requiring sasl validation) and then store the data to "HBase", "HBase" gives the following error

> java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:181)
>           at com.xueersi.datamining.ups.database.implement.HbaseClient.connect(HbaseClient.scala:91)
>           at com.xueersi.datamining.ups.stream.start.BaseInfoLogAnalysisStart$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BaseInfoLogAnalysisStart.scala:78)
>           at com.xueersi.datamining.ups.stream.start.BaseInfoLogAnalysisStart$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BaseInfoLogAnalysisStart.scala:75)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:925)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:925)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1956)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1956)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:325)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
>           ... 15 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ClusterId.parseFrom(ClusterId.java:64)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:75)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:105)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:931)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.(ConnectionManager.java:658)
>           ... 20 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainSaslServer$PlainSaslServerFactory.getMechanismNames(PlainSaslServer.java:163)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcServer$FastSaslServerFactory.(SaslRpcServer.java:381)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcServer.init(SaslRpcServer.java:186)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProtocolProxy(RPC.java:570)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNNProxyWithClientProtocol(NameNodeProxies.java:418)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:314)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider$DefaultProxyFactory.createProxy(ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider.java:68)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider.getProxy(ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider.java:152)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.(RetryInvocationHandler.java:75)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.(RetryInvocationHandler.java:66)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryProxy.create(RetryProxy.java:58)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:181)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:762)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:693)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:158)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2816)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:98)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2853)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2835)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:387)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:186)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DynamicClassLoader.initTempDir(DynamicClassLoader.java:120)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DynamicClassLoader.(DynamicClassLoader.java:98)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.(ProtobufUtil.java:246)
>           ... 25 more

But when I read another "Kafka" (without sasl validation), there was no problem with "HBase.
In addition, "HBase" is required for "kerberos" authentication
I think there is a conflict between kafka's sasl certification and hbase's kerberos certification
Is there anyone who can give me some advice?

Comment: Please paste the error so that other people can search for it. You're much more likely to receive an answer that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found the answer: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5294

Then I manually specify the dependencies(The version I used to use was 0.10.2.1)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

it works